# Copy what is different in dir1 to dir2 Rsync. Synchronize?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync, google

I want to copy what is different in dir 1 to dir 2 maintaining the structure, what is just different will be the content of each folder `/logs/` content, if it's the same then just overwrite, if it doesn't exist, then copy.

I'm trying with `rsync` but it doesn't work, it just creates another dir named with source in destination.

Some photos (the structure, content, folder names, order,  is the same, what just changes is the text files inside `/logs/` inside each code-username folder).

[![All code-username files in es51][1]][1]

As you can see `rsync` just creates the source folder in the destination, it's like a `cp -r source destination`, what I want is to overwrite logs so I have each logs files in each folder, maintaining the structure.

Comment: Please replace the screenshots with plain text. It's more legible, it's able to be parsed by search engines, and it saves space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `rsync` the contents of a directory and not the top level directory you have to end your directory arguments to `rsync` with a <kbd>/</kbd>.

Example:

```
 $ rsync /path/to/copy/ /path/to/put
```

This will take the contents of `/path/to/copy` but not the top level directory `copy` and sync it to `/path/to/put`. You don't need to do this, but I like this notation better because it really communicates the intent to others:

```
 $ rsync /path/to/copy/ /path/to/put/.
```

That says to copy the contents of `/path/to/copy` and put it in directory `/path/to/put/.`.

So in your screenshot example you'd do this:

```
$ screen -dmS Rsync \
  rsync --archive --progress /media/pi/copias/Tribal/ /media/pi/servidor/.
```

Comment: Thanks, now i think its working, 48 hours trying to solve these and what just a /. thanks really for your help you help me a lot dude.

Comment: @LocalHost - I've made the same mistake, glad to pay it forward 8-).